# Hibernate mapping for classes with inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, database-design, hibernate-mapping

I need help with the architecture of my classes. I am developing a system with several different actors and I put the common attributes in a parent class and extended the others from it. So I have ADMIN, CLIENT, MANAGER all extending from USER. I could not think of a smart way to do Hibernate mapping. I need to access a table with all the users. Should it be a table for each entity?

Also, if I have a Service for each class, would it be wise to have AdminService, ClientService, etc extend from UserService? How do I do that?

I am using the following architecture:
Controllers
Service
Domain
Repository

Project is in Spring boot, Java

Comment: can you put like an ERD and some code for us? It's a bit hard wrapping mind around what you asking for.

Comment: thiis   https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/ might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just like kamlesh commented, on https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/ you will find all standard approaches. Problem is not new and well supported by Hibernate

Comment: Thanks. This is all I needed